Are $\sigma$-localy compact sets exhaustible by compact sets?
Claim: Any countable union of compact subsets of a Euclidean space is exhaustible by compact sets.
Proof: If $F$ is a subset of a Euclidean space $X$, it is locally compact, because the Euclidean space itself is locally compact. In addition, if $F$ is a countable union of compact sets it is $\sigma$-compact. Putting the two properties together, it is $\sigma$-locally compact. $\sigma$-local compactness is equivalent to being exhausible by compact sets, i.e, there exist a nested sequence of compact subsets of $X$, $K_1 \subseteq K_2 \subseteq \cdots$ s.t. $F \supseteq \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nK_i$.
Is that reasoning correct?

"Claim" is false for $F=\Bbb Q$ (which is not $\sigma$-locally compact).

Thank you. Can you pls point out which step of the argument is wrong? I've learnt each of these steps from various sources but dunno if they work together.

The first sentence in the proof is false.

This is not true.  For example $\mathbb Q$ is $\sigma$-compact (it's a countable set of points).  But it is not exhaustible by compact sets, since it is not locally compact.
See also https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000027/properties/P000025.
